# How do I give each player a random unit in the start of the game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm making a kinda risk map in SC2 editor, I have placed cities around the map. How can I randomly split these cities among the players when the game starts?

Comment: Whoever VTC-ed this, this looks more like a [map editor question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544/185203), which is on-topic, than gamedev to me.